# Property description must be an object red screen error on new react-native app

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have initialized a new react-native app but I am getting the following red screen error even after not making any change in the code.

Java version - 8
node - 10.15.3
react-native - 0.57.3

I have initialized with a lower version of react-native because of encountering many errors in newer version. I am new to react-native. Please help.

App.js file.

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow
 */

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' + 'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android:
    'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

export default class App extends Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>{instructions}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

index.js

```
/** @format */

import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "GoSurf",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728",
    "react-native": "0.57.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "24.8.0",
    "jest": "24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.55.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Error shown: -

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-erzk1O-mZy6q-EuFBjE3qjhPgqmaMNA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I am having the same issue with running an already developed application and doesn't have any issue related to coding because the app works fine in other devices. Any luck with the issue??

Comment: The error got away when I removed the code from the directory, clone the project into a different directory. (Actually I did not understand how the error got fixed)

Answer (score 0):

Looking from the code posted I would guess it has to do with this line:

```
<Text style={styles.instructions}>{instructions}</Text>
```

instructions is an object and not a string

Answer (score 0):

No, `{ instructions }` is not an object -  at least we can't tell from that snippet.
It just says tells in JSX to inject the value for `instructions` inside the `<Text>` node

We ran into this issue today as well. Turned out it was redux's latest update.
revert to `redux@4.0.0` and the error will go away

Comment: The error still remains even after reverting to 4.0.0